# Using a C# application to control functions on a method?

Tags: c#, web, connection, traffic

this way seem vague, but I have certain tasks already coded in .net that I want to run from a website. I'm thinking some kind of call to the c sharp app to perform the task and return the results.

How would I make that connection is my question, how can I get my website to talk with my .net application.

Comment: Is you website developed in some programming language? Which one?

Comment: This question is probably too broad. However, one of the more common ways of interacting with a .NET app and a good place to start is using an API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing is a web service, usually either SOAP or REST.

SOAP is basically your desktop app sends an XML message to the web server saying, "Run this task and do it with these parameters." The server then returns a response also in XML.

REST is similar but not really tied to XML. It tends to be something you can just call via a special url like www.myserver.com/runtask/123 and it usually gives you a response in JSON format.

Since you're using C#, I'd recommend using SOAP because the .NET framework has a magic little feature called WCF that makes it a breeze to set up and consume SOAP services. So go Google around for a WCF tutorial on setting up your SOAP service on your website and a WCF tutorial on using it in your desktop app

Answer (score 0):

The question is a little vague....  for example...

If your .NET code you want to call can be wrapped in a DLL and this is a C# ASP.NET web site, attaching the DLL and running the code is easy.

If you want to run an external application that is on the web server from back-end processing, you can use System.Diagnostics.Process.

If your .NET code is on a separate machine from the web server, then you need some sort of communication between them, like SOAP, REST API, etc... as mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Use ASP.Net if you would want to develop a website with c#

> 

There are types of ASP.Net that you could choose

1. ASP.Net Web Forms (Old one) - looks similar with windows form application
2. ASP.Net MVC 5 (Not so old) - has a good structure for separation of concern
3. ASP.Net Core MVC (Latest) - similar with ASP.Net MVC 5 with some enhancements

---

- After you choose, I would recommend to finish a basic tutorial before starting coding.